# Different color for negative values in a comb plot

Tags: pgfplots, color, conditionals

I am using `pgfplots` for plotting simple comb plots. There are some negative values in the data. Right now all the data is plotted in same color. I would like to plot the negative values in the data in a different color. How can this be achieved?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis         cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot+ [
    ycomb,
] coordinates {
    (0,3) (1,-2) (2,4) (3,-1) (4,2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the question how to do this in general, i.e. plot all negative values in a different color, or just this plot. In the latter case, you might just add two plots: `\addplot+ [ ycomb,
] coordinates {
    (0,3) (2,4)  (4,2)
};
\addplot+ [
    ycomb,red
] coordinates {
    (1,-2) (3,-1) 
};`

Comment: I have many (~50) such plots, so I would want the answer to be generic.

Comment: Even if these are 50 points, you may be saving time by just adding two separate plots for positive and negative values. Most editors allow you to select the relevant coordinates with a regex search & replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As marmot already did in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413488/d#comment1032346_413488) I also suggest to separate positive and negative value to two different `\addplot`s. But to avoid separating positive and negative values by hand I would store the data in either an external file or a loaded table and then do some math with it.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % here the variant storing the data in a loaded table
    \pgfplotstableread{
        x   y
        0   3
        1   -2
        2   4
        3   -1
        4   2
    }{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % (moved common key here)
        ycomb,
    ]
        \draw [ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0)
            -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

        % first draw the positive values ...
        \addplot+ table [
            x=x,
            y expr={\thisrow{y} >=0 ? \thisrow{y} : NaN},
        ] {\loadedtable};

        % ... then draw the negative values by using the loaded table
        \addplot table [
            x=x,
            y expr={\thisrow{y} < 0 ? \thisrow{y} : NaN},
        ] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: So for each plot one has to load a separate table? Or it can be read from a single csv file where the data is saved?

Comment: Everything can be in one table.

Comment: I meant that I have to draw ~50 such graphs. I am not clear on how one can draw these graphs separately if we keep the data in just one table.

Comment: Aaah, ok. This can only be done when all data have the same length, i.e. have the same number of elements. Otherwise you have to fill up the "missing" ones with `NaN`. But without knowing the details of the source of the data I would recommend to store each table in a separate file.